# Mysterious Paddings by Chrome Mobile

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, mobile, mobile-chrome

I have a blog and I didn't change it for a long time. But when I visited my blog, I noticed these paddings on Chrome Mobile (Android). I used CSS Reset files and there wasn't any problem on Chrome Application.

### [image: Android View]

[image: Details of My Problem]

By the way, link of this page is 
http://zinzinzibidi.com/blog/genel/war_thunder_goklerin_fatihi_olun

The issue is only in Chrome Mobile. There is no problem with desktop Chrome.

How can I get rid of these paddings?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
html, body
{

    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;

}
```